# What distribution is this? (time until task completion and submission)

Tags: distributions, survival, lognormal-distribution, distribution-identification

I am looking at submission data—the length of time it takes for someone to complete a flow which involves submitting an item of content. I am getting the following distributions. I have two quick questions:

- What best describes the frequency distribution? I am thinking lognormal but am not sure.
- Is the mean the best statistic to use, e.g., 'mean submission time is hh:mm'? Is there a better, e.g., median or % of submissions below hh:mm?

[image: distribution of submission times]

Comment: If you want to be able to see the ways in which a density function deviates from lognormal, you might plot log(f) vs log(x) (which should be quadratic if the original density were lognormal). On the other hand, if you have *data*, a normal QQ plot of log(X) would be a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the real world, there is no distribution that's going to define this perfectly; parametric distributions are, at best, idealized descriptions of how the data is really distributed. That being said, it *appears* that something like a lognormal or wiebull distribution may be a reasonable description of the process you're observing. However, if dynamics change in the next data collection, this may no longer be the case. Summary: log normal or weibull is probably appropriate for *this* dataset.
2. I would be a little hesitant to use the mean, as it is heavily influenced by extreme values, for which this dataset has more than a few. The median might be a more important measure. But much more importantly, you want the measure that really answers your question of interest!

Comment: Agree on choosing a statistic that is aligned to what is needed - what I would like is to make improvements in the process and use the statistic as a basis of (a) comparison in time to track improvement (b) compare processes between different flows (which have same distro). Any ideas on pros cons (you mentioned median vs mean above)?

Comment: Two reasonable approaches: take a log transformation of the data and then perform a t-test. If the data is approximately log-normal, this will have the most power. Alternatively, you could use the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test and have pretty good power, regardless of whether it's approximately log-normal or not.